# Typescript onclick function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this code in my react js application:

```
 <button onClick={tes} type="button">click</button>
```

and this is my `tes` function:

```
const tes = (id: string) => {
    console.log(id)
}
```

If i hover over `onClick` function TS engine return:

```
TS2322: Type '(id: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.   Types of parameters 'id' and 'event' are incompatible.     Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Question: How to fix this and to add correct types?

Comment: The `event` is passed to the function as first parameter

Comment: Why _did_ you think `tes` would get called with a string when used as `onClick` for a `button`? What's unclear from the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the type of event that is passed as a parameter to the onClick handler function. But you can use a dummy middleware function and call your custom handler with a custom parameter by doing something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => tes("myid")} type="button">click</button>

const tes = (id: string) => {
    console.log(id)
}
```